# XML extra content at the end of document error

Tags: php, xml

I have written a very simple program with an XML file.
In some unknown reason I got this strange error:

This page contains the following errors:

error on line 2 at column 1: Extra content at the end of the document

my code is:

```
<?php
   header('Content-Type: text/xml');
   echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>';
   echo '<response>';
   echo 'no';
   echo '</response>';
?>
```

I am really frustrated what am I doing wrong??
Thanks to the helpers....

Answer (score 0):

That is server problem...
I placed your code in my website and tried it.
see http://aloneadi.cu.cc/pages/3.php

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.